# Does SIW report maximum or optimal RAM timings?

Tags: memory, timing, memory-timings

I ran [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) on my PC and, under the memory info for my PC, it reports my mobo supports "DRAM frequency 532.1 MHz" and the timing says "7-7-7-20"
Does this mean these are the max timings it supports, or the optimal?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the title clarification TomWij, that is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the RAM is running at those timings.

Screeny from CPU-Z on my laptop:

[image]

SIW:

[image]